# How put "NdT" symbol as a reference of footnote without change others footnotes?

Tags: numbering

I do not manage to know how to pose symbol of footnote. I wish to add a footnote whose connection box is NdT (note of the translator)  while the other footnotes continue their usual classification.

Thus for example, in a document creates with the class book, I wish to have in footnote the example below:

1   First note bla bla.

NdT. Footnote non numbering. Note of the translator being added in note of footer but
     without affecting the total classification of the other footnotes.

2   Second note on the same for exemple bla bla

3   Third note or not note... blab.

etc.

Who would have an idea to be able to do that? I did not find anything in documentation footnote, and the insertion of symbol is not appropriate because I wish to have the symbol “NdT”…

Thank for your attention
D. Collin

Comment: Try `footmisc` package.

Comment: I've already looking in footmisc documentation package. But I do not find how to do my wishes, or I do not understand how use \DefineFNsymbols...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `bigfoot`; I'd avoid a big footnote mark <sup>NdT</sup>, preferring a footnote symbol (reset per page).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{default}
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}[fnsymbol]
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteB}
\newcommand{\NdT}[1]{\footnoteB{\textit{NdT}: #1}}

\setlength{\textheight}{8cm} % just for the example

\begin{document}

Here is some text with an ordinary\footnote{An ordinary footnote.} footnote.

This text\NdT{This one is special.} needs a translator's note.\NdT{And another}

And another\footnote{Back to ordinariness.} ordinary footnoted text.

\newpage

Here is some text with an ordinary\footnote{An ordinary footnote.} footnote.

This text\NdT{This one is special.} needs a translator's note.

And another\footnote{Back to ordinariness.} ordinary footnoted text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank. It is exactly what I sought to do. All functions correctly, has condition of placing \usepackage{bigfoot} before \usepackage[frenchb]{Babel}. My problem is Resolu.

Answer (score 2):

here's one possibility.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\NdTfootnote}[1]{{%
  \let\@makefnmark\relax
  \textsuperscript{NdT}%
  \@footnotetext{\kern-.5em NdT. #1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Here is some text with an ordinary\footnote{An ordinary footnote.} footnote.

This text\NdTfootnote{This one is special.} needs a translator's note.

And another\footnote{Back to ordinariness.} ordinary footnoted text.

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

the (non)indentation of the NdT "label" can be adjusted as desired.

Comment: Thank. I try your script on my latex document (on documentclass{book}) but the Ndt footnote is preceded by a number… and don't appear like your precise exemple... I have : 1. NdT. bla bla... and not desire form : NdT. bla bla...

Comment: in your comment regarding the answer by @egreg, you mention that you are using `\usepackage[frenchb]{Babel}`.  i've tested with that package, and indeed, that causes the footnote to be numbered.  since egreg's answer works for you, use it.  (this is why it's really useful to know what packages are being used before trying to answer a question.)